# How to log user in and out in slim rest framework using slim session middleware?

Tags: php, rest, session, slim, middleware

I am using Slim framework to build a REST API and this is a rough application that I am using for development purposes. I want to log user in and out , and I set the session variable to the user id. The user is able to login perfectly fine in rest API but the remote device doesnt recognize the session (which means my $SESSION['id'] is empty) where as I clearly started this session in my host rest service. Here is my code:

```
require 'lib/Slim/Slim.php';
use lib\Slim\Middleware\SessionCookie;

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim(
    array(
'cookies.encrypt' => true,
    'cookies.secret_key' => 'my_secret_key',
    'cookies.cipher' => MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
    'cookies.cipher_mode' => MCRYPT_MODE_CBC
        )
);

$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\SessionCookie(array(
    'expires' => '20 minutes',
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => '',
    'secure' => false,
    'httponly' => false,
    'name' => 'slim_session',
    'secret' => '',
    'cipher' => MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
    'cipher_mode' => MCRYPT_MODE_CBC
)));

$app->get("/login/:string", function($string) use ($app)
        {
            $input = json_decode($string);
            try 
            {
                if ($input->username && $input->password) 
                    {
                        $user = Model::factory('Users')->where("username",$input->username)->where("password",md5($input->password))->find_one();
                        //$app->setCookie('user_id',$user->id);
                            session_cache_limiter(false);
                            session_start();
                       $_SESSION['id'] =  $user->id;

                        $status = 'success';
                        $message = 'Logged in successfully.';
                    } 
                else
                        {
                            $status = false;
                            $message = 'Could not log you in. Please try again.';
                        }

            }
            catch (Exception $e) 
                    {
                        $status = 'danger';
                        $message = $e->getMessage();
                    }
            $response = array(
                'status' => $status,
                'message' => $message
            );
            $app->response()->header("Content-Type", "application/json");
            echo json_encode($response);

        });



        $app->get("/logout",function() use ($app)
        {


            try {
                        unset($_SESSION['id']);
                        session_destroy();
                        session_start();

                        //$app->getCookie('user_id');

                        $status = 'success';
                        $message = 'You have been logged out successfully';
                    } 

            catch (Exception $e) 
                    {
                        $status = 'danger';
                        $message = $e->getMessage();
                    }
            $response = array(
                'status' => $status,
                'message' => $message
            );

            $app->response()->header("Content-Type", "application/json");
            echo json_encode($response);

        });
```

It is returning 'Logged in successfully' but isn't actually logging me in so in my application when I check `isset($_SESSION['id'])`  , there is nothing in the variable. Does anyone know whats going on? I am really confused  because according to the slim documentation , it says :

> > The session cookie middleware will work seamlessly with the $_SESSION superglobal so you can easily migrate to this session
> >     storage middleware with zero changes to your application code.
>
> If you use the session cookie middleware, you DO NOT need to start a
>   native PHP session. The $_SESSION superglobal will still be available,
>   and it will be persisted into an HTTP cookie via the middleware layer
>   rather than with PHP’s native session management.

Answer (score 0):

The issue would seem to be that you are not starting your session soon enough not anything with session middleware I would place `session_start()` at the top of the index

```
require 'lib/Slim/Slim.php';
use lib\Slim\Middleware\SessionCookie;
session_start();
```

Now it is started every time your application routes. So in login and logout remove your `session_start()` calls. Now in logout route redirect to your landing page or somewhere like:

```
$app->redirect('/yourawesomepage');
```

that recalls `session_start()` so you can remove that from here your logout route.

Comment: Thankyou @nerdlyist Are you sure that I don't have to send anything in the json headers like a session cookie or something?

Comment: @Daniel Not that I am aware of. PHP will handle its own session ID if that is what you are referring to.